# Check if a string has all the characters of another string

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

```java
String one = "This is a test";
String two = "This is a simple test";
```

I want to check if `two` contains all the characters that are in `one`, and ignore the fact it has extra characters.

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you know an answer can you tell us, or link to it?

Comment: You could try splitting both strings using white spaces and search for the array elements.

Comment: When you say "contains all the characters" do you mean: 1) characters in string1 are contained in string2 in the same sequence overlooking extra characters 2) every character in string 1 is also present in string2 regardless of number of occurrences or 3) every character in string 1 is contained at least as many times in string 2?

Comment: If we had String 3 = "This a test", it would be missing "is" and therefore would not pass the test

Comment: Does the order matter? What should the result be if `two` is `"DOG"` and `one` is `"GO"`? Should it be `true` because `G` and `O` are both in `"DOG"` or `false` because the letters are switched?

Comment: @pbabcdefp Read this help page about [good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then you know, why this question isn't a good one. I guess that is why some people decided to downvote.

Comment: @Tom There is a good question hidden here. The question just needs to be clearer. I think it's best to ask for more details rather than just downvote and say nothing.

Comment: @pbabcdefp There is a good question hidden there? This whole post contains an assignment that other should solve for him. He no even asked something.

Comment: @Tom How do you know it's an assigment?

Comment: @gab06 Look at that post: he says what he wants. And who do you think should give him that? It is an assignment for "us".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fastest thing would probably be to break them up to `HashSet`s and then apply `containsAll`

```
public static Set<Character> stringToCharacterSet(String s) {
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        set.add(c);
    }
    return set;
}

public static boolean containsAllChars
    (String container, String containee) {
    return stringToCharacterSet(container).containsAll
               (stringToCharacterSet(containee));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String one = "This is a test";
    String two = "This is a simple test";
    System.out.println (containsAllChars(one, two));
}
```

Comment: @gab06 thanks for noticing! Fixed.

Comment: It will not work if we check strings "ABCD" and "ACC". It will return 'true' as C will be compared once.

Comment: I agree with @korujzade

Answer (score 2):

```
static boolean stringContains(String longer, String shorter) {
    int i = 0;
    for (char c : shorter.toCharArray()) {
        i = longer.indexOf(c, i) + 1;
        if (i <= 0) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It works, but it's slow because of the O(n*m) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple loop over the set of the characters in the first string:

```
String s1 = "This is a test";
String s2 = "This is a simple test";
Set<Character> chars = new HashSet<Character>();
for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
    chars.add(s1.charAt(i));
}


for (Iterator<Character> iterator = chars.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Character character = iterator.next();
    if(!s2.contains(character.toString())) {
        // break and mark as not contained
        break;
    }
}
```

If words are meant to be checked, then you could split the string around whitespaces into a list of words:

```
String[] words1 = s1.split("\\s");
String[] words2 = s2.split("\\s");

List<String> wordList1 = Arrays.asList(words1);
List<String> wordList2 = Arrays.asList(words2);
System.out.println(wordList2.containsAll(wordList1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I know it's long but it works

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String String1,String2;
    int i, j, count1, count2;
    count1 = 0;
    count2 = 0;
    String1 = "This is a test";
    String2 = "This is a simple test";
    char[] list1 = new char[String2.length()];
    char[] list2 = new char[String2.length()];
    char[] list3 = new char[String2.length()];
    for (i = 0; i <= String1.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        list1[i] = String1.charAt(i);
        for (j = 0; j <= String2.length() - 1; j++)
        {
            list2[j] = String2.charAt(j);
            if (list1[i] == list2[j])
            {
                i++;
                count1++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= String1.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        list1[i] = String1.charAt(i);
        for (j = 0; j <= String1.length() - 1; j++)
        {
            list3[j] = String1.charAt(j);
            if (list1[i] == list3[j])
            {
                i++;
                count2++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (count1 >= count2)
        System.out.println(true);
    else
        System.out.println(false);
}
```

Comment: Well, I have some questions about this: why do you use arrays, if you just compare the results of `String1.charAt(i)` and `String2.charAt(j)`? Why do you increment the counting variable of the outer loops if a specific character matches another one? And finally: what is the purpose of the second loop block, when you just check that `String1` contains the same characters as `String1`?

Comment: In the first loop I compare String1 with String2. Count1 is the number  of the same characters between String 1 and String 2. I didn't a character if it is used before. In the second loop I compared String1 with itself to see that how many different characters String1 have. Count2 is the number of different characters in String2

Comment: Can you do me a favor? Change `String1` to `"This is a test x"` and see if your code still works. The problem with your `i++` is that it skips characters of `String1`.

Comment: Yes there seem to be a problem in here

Comment: As a side note, the code from the end could be replaced with `System.out.println(count1 >= count2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
two.startsWith(one)
```

If you aren't sure about the start position (the above assumes 0), try using the following API

```
startsWith(String, offset)
```

Comment: This is not what OP whats. `one` doesn't need to be a complete substring of `two` to contain the same characters. For example `test ; estt` would fail with your method.

Comment: @Tom I see now there is a conversation below the original question. However,the time I answered, there was no such conversation and hence I interpreted it that way.